# boundedness of integral of a bounded function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $a(t)$ be a bounded function. Is $\int_0^xa(t)dt$ also bounded for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}?$

Comment: Suggestion: what happens if $a$ is constant?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear, which might explain why you got two contradictory answers (both being correct, depending on how one interprets your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $a(t) \equiv 1$, then your integral is $x$, which is not bounded on $\mathbb R^+$

Comment: Except a constant function are there any counter example?

Comment: @andii yes, obviously, don't you really see them?

Comment: i cant see a non trivial example will be very useful for me.

Comment: $a(t) = 0 : t < 1; = \dfrac{1}{t} : t\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^x a(t)dt$ is bounded by $L x$ if $L$ is a bound for $a$.

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: @andii My answer says yes, with a linear dependence on $x$, though. The answer of BaronTV shows that you cannot do better.